# PrestaShop - How to add a variable to an e-mail template

Tags: prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I recently purchased a review module for PrestaShop 1.7.5.

I'd like to add the customer's phone number to the email is sent by the module. But the tech support told me customizations are not covered by modules support, has to do by myself.

So, I try to do it myself.

I found the template variable code in LGMailer.php:

```
    $template_vars = array(
        '{firstname}' => $order['firstname'],
        '{lastname}'  => $order['lastname'],
        '{storename}' => Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_NAME'),
        '{email}'     => $order['email'],
        '{id_order}'  => $order['id_order'],
        '{link}'      => $link,
        '{product_details}' => $products
    );

    return $template_vars;
```

as I want to add customer phone so modified it like this:

```
     $template_vars = array(
        '{firstname}' => $order['firstname'],
        '{lastname}'  => $order['lastname'],
        '{storename}' => Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_NAME'),
        '{email}'     => $order['email'],
        '{phone_mobile}'     => $order['phone_mobile'],        (Added this line)
        '{id_order}'  => $order['id_order'],
        '{link}'      => $link,
        '{product_details}' => $products
    );

    return $template_vars;
}
```

But It doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? attached is the php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getTemplateVars()` method from your module is called in the cron.php file and is using the `getOrders()` from the `LGMailer` class to retrieve orders for which e-mails will be sent.

If you look closely at this method, you will see that it does not select the mobile phone column, you would need to add it.

Edit the `getOrders()` method in `LGMailer.php`:

**First, add the missing column**

```
$query->select('a.`phone_mobile`');
```

**Then, add a JOIN statement base on the delivery address**

```
$query->leftJoin('address', 'a', 'o.`id_address_delivery` = a.`id_address`');
```

**Finally**

Don't forget to add `{phone_mobile}` inside `opinion-request.html`
(which you forgot to attach to your question).

I hope this helps!

Comment: You're very welcome! As this is a paid module, don't forget to delete it from your Drive, don't make it publicly accessible to everyone. You can mark this answer as accepted :-)